# Rank Mismatch error in TensorFlow concat

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I have been trying to make a simple 2 layered neural network. I studied the tensorflow api and official tutorials, I made the one layered model, but am having trouble in the neural network. Here is a section of my code that is causing the error:

```
with graph.as_default():
    tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, image_size * image_size))
    tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
    tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
    tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

    weights0 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([image_size**2, num_labels]))
    biases0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_labels]))

    hidden1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_test_dataset, weights0) + biases0)

    weights1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_labels, image_size * image_size]))
    biases1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([image_size**2]))

    hidden2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden1, weights1) + biases1)


    logits = tf.matmul(hidden2, weights0) + biases0

    labels = tf.expand_dims(tf_train_labels, 1)

    indices = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(0, batch_size), 1)

    concated = tf.concat(1, [indices, tf.cast(labels,tf.int32)])

    onehot_labels = tf.sparse_to_dense(concated, tf.pack([batch_size, num_labels]), 1.0, 0.0)


    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, onehot_labels))

    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)

    train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_valid_dataset,weights0) + biases0),weights1)+biases1),weights0)+biases0)
    test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_test_dataset,weights0) + biases0),weights1)+biases1),weights0)+biases0)
```

the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./test1.py", line 60, in <module>
    concated = tf.concat(1, [indices, tf.cast(labels,tf.int32)])
    File "/Users/username/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 309, in concat
    name=name)
    File "/Users/username/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 70, in _concat
    name=name)
    File "/Users/username/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 664, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
    File "/Users/username/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1836, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
    File "/Users/username/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1476, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
    File "/Users/username/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 364, in _ConcatShape
    concat_dim + 1:].merge_with(value_shape[concat_dim + 1:])
    File "/Users/username/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 527, in merge_with
    self.assert_same_rank(other)
    File "/Users/username/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 570, in assert_same_rank
    "Shapes %s and %s must have the same rank" % (self, other))
    ValueError: Shapes TensorShape([]) and TensorShape([Dimension(10)]) must have the same rank
```

Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/sX7RqbAf

I have used TensorFlow and Python 2.7. I am quite new to neural nets and machine learning so pardon me for any mistakes, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example:

- `tf_train_labels` has shape `[batch_size, num_labels]`
- Therefore `labels` has shape `[batch_size, 1, num_labels]`
- `indices` has shape `[batch_size, 1]`

Therefore, when you write:

```
concated = tf.concat(1, [indices, tf.cast(labels,tf.int32)])
```

it throws an error, because the third dimension of `labels` and `indices` is different.  `labels` has a third dimension of size `num_labels` (presumably 10), and `indices` has no third dimension.

Comment: can you please tell me how to fix that?

Comment: It's hard to know how to fix it without knowing exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  Judging by the fact that you're trying to convert sparse to dense, and you're using a softmax cross entropy (rather than, say, sigmoid), I'd guess you're modeling a single-label rather than multi-label classification network.  In that case, your `tf_train_labels` tensor is already dense, as is `logits`, so I don't think you need to convert anything from sparse to dense.  So I'd just omit the computation of `onehot_labels` and just directly compute the `loss` based on `tf_train_labels` and `logits`.